# Form serialize with ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I was trying to post the form data with onclick event in an ajax function.but the data are not being posted in the next page. I was using the serialize method of from data submission but its not working. Meanwhile when I use jQuery `.val` function it captures the right data in th right field

Here is my html:

```
             <form id="customer_from"  class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-lg-2">
                      <div id="customer_information" style="background-color:grey;padding:5px;text-align:center;border:1px solid white;cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;height:50px;font-size:15px;" data-registry-id="<?php echo $_POST['order_number']; ?>" data-order-ref="<?php echo $_POST['order_ref'];  ?>" data-registry-type="<?php echo $_POST['registry_type'];  ?>" data-customer-id="<?php echo $data['customer_id'];?>">
                         Customer Information
                      </div>
                      <div id="registry_details" style="background-color:grey;padding:5px;text-align:center;border:1px solid white;cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;height:50px;font-size:15px;" data-registry-id="<?php echo $_POST['order_number']; ?>" data-order-ref="<?php echo $_POST['order_ref'];  ?>" data-registry-type="<?php echo $_POST['registry_type'];  ?>" data-customer-id="<?php echo $data['customer_id'];?>">
                         Registry Details
                      </div>
                      <div id="send_email" style="background-color:grey;padding:5px;text-align:center;border:1px solid white;cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;height:50px;font-size:15px;"  data-registry-id="<?php echo $_POST['order_number']; ?>" data-order-ref="<?php echo $_POST['order_ref'];  ?>" data-registry-type="<?php echo $_POST['registry_type'];  ?>" data-customer-id="<?php echo $data['customer_id'];?>">
                         E-mail
                      </div>
                      <div id="add_comment" style="background-color:grey;padding:5px;text-align:center;border:1px solid white;cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;height:50px;font-size:15px;" data-registry-id="<?php echo $_POST['order_number']; ?>" data-order-ref="<?php echo $_POST['order_ref'];  ?>" data-registry-type="<?php echo $_POST['registry_type'];  ?>" data-customer-id="<?php echo $data['customer_id'];?>">
                         Add Comment
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-lg-10" id="dynamic" >
                      <div class="col-lg-5">
                         <label for='customer_id'> Customer ID: <span class='required-field'>*</label>
                         <input name='customer_id'  type='text' value="<?php echo $data['customer_id'] ?>" class='form-control' required /> </span>
                         <label for='customer_name'> Customer Name: <span class='required-field'>*</label>
                         <input name='customer_name'  type='text' value="<?php echo $data['firstname'] ?>" class='form-control' required /> </span>
                         <label for='customer_email'> E-mail: <span class='required-field'>*</label>
                         <input name='customer_email'  type='text' value="<?php echo $data['email'] ?>" class='form-control' required /> </span>
                         <label for='customer_telephone1'> Telephone#1: <span class='required-field'>*</label>
                         <input name='customer_telephone1'  type='text' value="<?php echo $data['phone'] ?>" class='form-control' required /> </span>
                         <label for='customer_telephone2'> Telephone#2:<span class='required-field'>*</label>
                         <input name='customer_telephone2'  type='text' value="<?php echo $data['alt_phone'] ?>" class='form-control' required /> </span>
                         <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="yes">Pattern</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-5">
                         <label for='customer_address'> Address: <span class='required-field'>*</label>
                         <input name='customer_address'  type='text' value="<?php echo $data['address'] ?>" class='form-control' required /> </span>
                         <label for='customer_city'> City: <span class='required-field'>*</label>
                         <input name='customer_city'  type='text' value="<?php echo $data['city'] ?>" class='form-control' required /> </span>
                         <label for='customer_province'> Province: <span class='required-field'>*</label>
                         <input name='customer_province'  type='text' value="<?php echo $data['province'] ?>" class='form-control' required /> </span>
                         <label for='customer_postal'> Postal code: <span class='required-field'>*</label>
                         <input name='customer_postal'  type='text' value="<?php echo $data['postal_code'] ?>" class='form-control' required /> </span>
                         <label for='customer_country'> Country: <span class='required-field'>*</label>
                         <select id = "customer_country" name="customer_country" class="form-control" title="Select a Category" required>
                            <?php echo $customer_country; ?>
                         </select>
                         <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="yes">Newsletter</label>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-11 col-md-12">
                      <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="update-registry" value="Update Registry" style="float:right;">
                      <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete-registry" data-registry="<?php echo $_POST['order_ref'];?>" data-type="<?php echo $_POST['registry_type']; ?>" value="Delete" style="float:left;">
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </form>
```

and here is the ajax call:

```
$("#update-registry").on("click",function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/update_customer.php",
        data:$("from#customer_form").serializeArray(),
        beforeSend: function() {

        },
        success: function(msg) {
            $("#registry").find(".update_registry").html(msg);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("failure");
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: 'It's not working' is never enough information. What behaviour are you expecting? What actually happens? Is the request sent? What is the data in the request? Is there an error in the PHP code? Have you checked the server logs or client console? Help us to help you.

Comment: request sent is completed but when i went to see the vairables that got passed it was just blank and i'm sending it to the blank php file so no errors in php  and i was checking the console to see the post tab@RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the form ID:

```
<form id="customer_from"
```

There is a typo:

```
 data:$("from#customer_form").serializeArray(),
 //------^^^^----------^^^^should be from
 //------^^^^should be form
```

change `from` to `form`. Even better as IDs are unique so there is no need to prefix the tag name:

```
 data:$("#customer_from").serializeArray(),
```

Comment: still got nothing @Jai

Comment: what is the issue now? check the request in the network tab and see if you find anything in the form-data?

Comment: same no data is getting posted in the ajax call and checking from the network tab but there is no data in param tab that's the problem

Comment: Are you sure you don't have duplicate form with same ID? it might be possible.

Comment: @Etherealsoul actually the form id also has a typo: `customer_form` has to be `customer_from`.